# Android End to End testing with calabash

Tags: android, functional-testing

I am new to using calabash for android, which is a end to end testing framework for android. Iam trying to test a feature where on pressing a button in my app I am taken back to the android home screen. Could someone help me with the test for this scenario? Here is what I have till now

```
Feature: Return to Home Screen

   Scenario: As a user 
     When I press the "GO" button
     Then I should see "HomeActivity" screen appear
```

I am stuck at the second line. I have tried several alternatives like trying to use the id (Don't think I got the correct id. Does the android home activity have a predefined id?) or different names to test if the home activity appears.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a new action to do exactly that on [my github branch](https://github.com/nalbion/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/test-server/instrumentation-backend/src/sh/calaba/instrumentationbackend/actions/view/GetActivityName.java)

For TabActivities it returns the tag of the current tab.
For other Activities it returns the class name.

```
actual_activity = performAction('get_activity_name')['bonusInformation']
raise Exception "Expected #{expected_activity} activity but was #{actual_activity}" unless actual_activity == expected_activity
```